# Android canvas , how to get a sub path from existing path?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have a Bezier curved path in `canvas` starting from `(0,0)` and ending in `(canvasWidth,0)` , with a control point at `(canvasWidth,canvasHeight)`

its drawing properly and Im getting a curved line. Im drawing it using the `path.quadTo` method as shown below

```
          path.moveTo(mPointStart.x, mPointStart.y);
          path.quadTo(mControlPoint.x, mControlPoint.y, mPointEnd.x, mPointEnd.y);
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Now, I want to draw a sub path over this existing path. Say if I want to draw half of the path ,

I want to overdraw the same path till half of the way using some other paint, so that half of the path will be in one color, other half will be in the old color. How can I find the points till half of the existing path?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the way I did this (in Kotlin), was to use the PathMeasure class. It doesn't look the best, but it works! So please post any tidier answers.

```
private fun getSubPath(path: Path, start: Float, end: Float): Path {
    val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(path, false)
    val point = FloatArray(2)
    val subPath = Path()
    var startFound = false
    var startDistance = start
    var endDistance = end

    while (pathMeasure.nextContour()) {
        val length = pathMeasure.length
        startDistance -= length
        endDistance -= length

        if (!startFound) {
            if (startDistance <= 0) {
                startFound = true
                val startPoint = length + startDistance

                pathMeasure.getPosTan(startPoint, point, null)
                subPath.moveTo(point[0], point[1])

                if (startDistance < 0) {
                    val endPoint = length + endDistance
                    pathMeasure.getPosTan(endPoint, point, null)
                    subPath.lineTo(point[0], point[1])

                    if (endDistance <= 0) {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            val endPoint = length + endDistance
            pathMeasure.getPosTan(endPoint, point, null)
            subPath.lineTo(point[0], point[1])

            if (endDistance <= 0) {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return subPath
}
```

The parameters `start` and `end` can't be smaller then 0 or larger then the path's total length.

The way to use this is by the following:

```
private fun usePathFunction() {
    val start = pathsTotalLength * 0.25
    val end = pathsTotalLength * 0.75

    val subPath = getSubPath(path, start, end)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using [getSegment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure) is the proper answer to this question:

```
private fun getSubPath(path: Path, start: Float, end: Float): Path {
        val subPath = Path()
        val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(path, false)
        pathMeasure.getSegment(start * pathMeasure.length, end * pathMeasure.length, subPath, true)
        return subPath
    }
```

usage:

```
val subPath = getSubPath(path = originalPath, start = 0.2f, end = 0.8f)
```

Comment: Amazing, this makes animation possible and easy